# How to redirect to https cpanel that has multiple domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have 3 domains, www.1.com (primany), 2.com (addon)and 3.com (addon) hosted at cPanel (Linux) in single account.

I'm planning to redirect only 1.com to https and not to disturb on other 2 domains, but as i add these codes at .htaccess root, all my other domains get redirected to https://1.com as well.

How do i ensure, only 1.com get redirected to https, without getting all other domain directed to https://1.com/

### code that i added

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56  .php56 .php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Using `1.php` as the name of the PHP file you want redirected you can write an if condition to check if `1.php` was called or some other file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 1\.php
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out, i've edited the .htaccess at root directory by add these at top:

---

```
RewriteOptions inherit    
RewriteEngine on    
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56  .php56 .php    
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1\.com$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.1\.com$    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://1.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```